# Storing where-conditions in a table for use in dynamic sql statements

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table where there are conditions.How to concatenate in a t-sql
condition table

```
SAL
sal >100
sal < 100
sal=500

SELECT SAL  into #sal from condtbl
Select Top 1 @sal = event From #sal

`select * from emp where @sal`
```

How can I accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is a very good idea, there are a lot of factors that can break your query, having the right columns on the conditions table, besides the fact that you'll need to deal with [dynamic sql](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html). Anyway, this is one approach for what you want:

```
DECLARE @sal NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @sal = SAL
FROM condtbl
WHERE IdCondition = 1 -- an example, don't rely on TOP 1 without ORDER BY

SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM emp WHERE ' + @sal

EXEC(@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your conditions are stored in a table as valid tsql, then the dynamic tsql approach is the best way to go.

Not sure if it's an option for you, but if you can re-evaluate the approach, there might be something better than storing conditions like this.  For example:

```
select * from emp where [sal] BETWEEN @minSAL AND @maxSAL
```

This would require you to have 2 input variables as you can see -- but it would cover all 3 bases `(>,<,=)` just depending on which values you passed.